# If same elements are referring same objects in Python datatypes (string/list/tuples) then how the size of the variable is determined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

We know that in `Python` the same character values within a `string` have the same ID value (same concept for `list` & `tuple`), as for example:

```
>>> var = 'wwww'
>>> print(id[0])
>>> 88293056
>>> print(id[1])
>>> 88293056
>>> print(id[2])
>>> 88293056
>>> print(id[3])
>>> 88293056
```

This is because all the positions (0 to 3) are referring the same object `w` in memory.
But what about the size of the `string`? If we see the size of variable `var` then it is showing `29`.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(var)
>>> 29
>>> sys.getsizeof('wwww')
>>> 29
>>> sys.getsizeof('www')
>>> 28
>>> sys.getsizeof('ww')
>>> 27
>>> sys.getsizeof('w')
>>> 26
```

Is this means for each character its taking `1 Byte` within the string? then why `sys.getsizeof('')` is returning `25`? is it the default size getting allocated for a string?

If all the positions are referring at the same object constant in memory (id value 88293056) then size of the variable `var` should be same as one character's size.

Similar thing is happening for `list` also.

```
>>> var = [1,1]
>>> print(id(var[0]))
>>> 1734203568
>>> print(id(var[1]))
>>> 1734203568
>>> sys.getsizeof(a[1])
14
>>> sys.getsizeof(a[0])
14
>>> sys.getsizeof(var)
>>> 44
```

Need some explanation about these.

Comment: I don't put a lot of stock into things like `sys.getsizeof`. Right now, I have a IPython command line where `sys.getsizeof('a') > sys.getsizeof('aaa')` is `True` (yet it is `False` if I open a new interpreter).

Comment: your first statement is actually incorrect, try `var = [-6, -6]` and you'll see the `id()` are different, however, i don't think this is very relevant to your subsequent question anyway

Comment: anyway, what do you expect `sys.getsizeof` to return in all these examples?

Comment: @Kris I am confused about the size determination not the IDs. How sizes are determined if same objects are referred?

Comment: size function is applied on the value not id.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Its not incorrect the '-6' is out of the lower integer caching range (-5 to 256), that is why is giving different ID. That I know. I am confused about the size calculation.

Comment: @Kris If size of one character is 1 Byte then the size of the variable should not increase by 1 every time because all are same ('w') characters getting referred. Here is my confusion.

Comment: Each object has a size in memory. This does not always relate to the exact byte-size multiple. There can be other information about the type involved. If you say 'www' this actually creates a string object in memory with 3*size(w)+size(type_info) and more. Look to internals if you want more info. So inferring the size to be a byte-multiple is not right.

Comment: @Kris Thats something interesting, so even if within an sequence all elements are referring same constant or NOT, for both case the sizing calculation of a variable is little bit different as you told. This is not depending on Bytes of individual items.

>>> sys.getsizeof('x')
26
>>> sys.getsizeof('w')
26
>>> sys.getsizeof('wx')
27
... this is not 26 + 26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We know that in Python the same character values within a string have the same ID value

Totally wrong.

First, "character values" have no id at all since python has no `character` type - a one-character string is still a string.

Then, the fact that CPython does intern some strings (as well as some integers) is an implementation detail, it's specific to the CPython implementation and is in no way part of the language itself (other implementations may not do so, or may do it according to other rules etc).

> (same concept for list & tuple)

Definitly not:

```
>>> f = [{"foo":42}, {"foo": 42}]
>>> id(f[0]) 
139669285840048
>>> id(f[1]) 
139669257272968
>>> f[0] == f[1]
True
```

Or did you meant "for lists of strings and tuples of strings" ? If yes, same answer as for strings: it's only a product of CPython's strings interning and is in no way part of the language specifications.

> This is because all the positions (0 to 3) are referring the same object w in memory.

Cf above. The string `"www"` is **not** made of three references to the string `"w"`, and the evaluation of the expression `"www"[0]` actually yields a new string built from the first character of `"www"` - or, in the case of the CPython implementation, it first lookup it's cache, then either build a new string, cache it and return it, or just return the cached one, which is why you get the same ids.

wrt/ `sys.getsizeof` results, you have to understand that Python is not C. Python objects are not C scalar values but complex data structures (implemented mostly as structs containting pointers to other structs etc in CPython). Also, when a Python object references another (object's attributes, lists or tuples contents, dicts values etc), what's stored in the inner data structure is not the referenced object but only a reference to it, so what `sys.getsizeof` will use is the size of the reference (a PyObject pointer in CPython), not the size of the referenced object:

```
>>> l = ["foo"]
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
80
>>> l[0] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavvvvvvvvvvvvvvv"
>>> sys.getsizeof(l)
80
>>>
```

> Similar thing is happening for list also.
>
> > > var = [1,1]

CPython *also* caches "small" integers (for a definition of "small" that changed quite a few  times... IIRC in 1.5.2 it was something like 255 or less). What you're seeing here are the size of a CPython `int`  object and the minimal size (a larger list will have a larger size since it has to store more references) of a CPython `list` object *on your system* (those values can change depending on CPython version, target OS and compilation flags).

Also, wrt/ lists, CPython has some (once again implementation-specific) optimisations to avoid reallocating memory each time you append something, so do not expect a linear "list len -> list size" relation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.